# Owncloud json api

Tags: json, owncloud

Does anyone know how to integrate with owncloud via json?

I'm coming for the point that if we implement owncloud in my organization, i will like to have the ability to build features into the ios app.

Comment: I personally don't think that you can build anything into the ios app. You can however build your own ios app and let it communicate with ownclouds core features or your own owncloud app.

Comment: @MerlinDenker The iOS owncloud client is open source like all of their software components. You certainly can modify it, why not?

Comment: This is probably a little late, but if anyone is looking for to write an ios app for owncloud, there's a repo on github. https://github.com/owncloud/ios

Answer (score 0):

You can access the share API using REST:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/core/ocs-share-api.html